# For react-native images is there a performance benefit to adding static images directly to native projects?

Tags: performance, react-native

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@adamjacobb/react-native-performance-images-adf5843e120) claims that loading static images in react native can gain a huge performance boost simply from copying the images to the native packages instead of letting the react native bundler handle them. The idea is that images included by the react native bundler must be copied over the bridge while images compiled into the native projects do not. I have not been able to discern from the react-native code and docs whether or not this is true.

Is there a performance benefit to adding static images directly to the native projects in react native rather than letting the react native bundler handle them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The app on the left `requires` local static images and the one on the right uses images bundled into the app (as suggested in the blog post you mention). The speed difference is significant.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting. Do you have this connected to any sort of benchmark? What sort of work is RN doing on the left? Is any of that blocking to the JS or UI threads?

Comment: The *only* difference is that I use `rain = require('./icons/sp_rain.png')` on the left and `rain = {uri: 'sp_rain'}` on the right

Comment: Both versions are overlaying 3 png images to form the completed symbol. That's about 375 <Image/> elements in total.

Comment: Strangely <Profiler/> doesn't show much difference in duration between the two versions.

Comment: The slow version isn't blocking, the screen still scrolls as the images draw in.